# How do I run a 32bit programme on amd64 server?

Tags: linux, 64-bit, gentoo, architecture

As a followup to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/49852/bash-cant-start-a-programme-thats-there-and-has-all-the-right-permissions), I have discovered that this closed source programme is 32bit and I have an amd64 server. The server is gentoo that has recently been upgraded.

What do I need to install in order to make this programme work? I know it's possible because I have another gentoo amd64 server that can run this programme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Gentoo there is a series of packages which contain 32-bit binaries of all the common system libraries for precisely this purpose. Do a search for `emul-linux` using `equery` and you'll get the list. Usually you need at least `app-emulation/emul-linux-x86-baselibs` and `app-emulation/emul-linux-x86-compat` but there are a few others which pertain to X11 apps.

The other options are running a [multilib](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/gentoo-amd64-faq.xml#multilib) environment or setting up an [32-bit chroot](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/base/amd64/howtos/chroot.xml).